# how to check app is installed in my fb page or not using PHP, Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to check particular app is installed in my fb page or not using PHP, Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Using the graph api, you can't view apps you have installed, only apps you own (either as an administrator,developer,tester, or insight user): https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN